# how to get value of a template field label of a gridview, getting error Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

While getting the value I'm getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object. how to get labeled label value in code behind. How to get the value in custom event

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridviewQuoteDetails" EmptyDataText="No records Found..." AutoGenerateEditButton="false" OnRowEditing="gridviewQuoteDetails_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="gridviewQuoteDetails_RowUpdating" DataKeyNames="id" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <a href='Quote.aspx?val=<%#Eval("id")%>'>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval ("id")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </a>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Text="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" Text="Update" runat="server" OnClick="OnUpdate" />

        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>


        code behind


     protected void OnUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                string qouteid = ((Label)gridviewQuoteDetails.FindControl("lblid")).Text;
                GridViewRow row = (sender as LinkButton).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
                string id = (row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
                string Description = (row.Cells[1].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;  
        }
```

Comment: Where you want to get it? I mean which event?

Comment: protected void OnUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

           
            string qouteid = ((Label)gridviewQuoteDetails.FindControl("lbllnknm")).Text;

Comment: What is onupdate? when it gets called?

Comment: @krishnamohan - What is _OnUpdate_ event? Is this custom event handler? Or you are trying to access it in `OnRowEditing` event?

Comment: im not accessing in row editing im accessing in template field.on click event of link button

Comment: <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" Text="Update" runat="server" OnClick="OnUpdate" />..i updated my question please check it

Comment: @krishnamohan - Okay got it! Check `Update 2` in my answer. BTW you should provide these information while posting the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Gridview` is a collection of rows right, but you are trying to search the control directly within the gridview thus `((LinkButton)gridviewQuoteDetails.FindControl("lbllnknm"))` will be null and when you are trying to access the `Text` property of LinkButton you are getting NRE error.

You need to loop through the rows of your gridview control to access each linkbutton present in each row like this:-

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gridviewQuoteDetails.Rows)
{
    LinkButton lbllnknm= row.FindControl("lbllnknm") as LinkButton;
}
```

But ideally you would not be needing this. I guess you are trying to get the value in `OnRowEditing` event handler. If that is the case then you can fetch the value of linkbutton like this:-

```
protected void gridviewQuoteDetails_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string qouteid = ((Label)gridviewQuoteDetails.Rows[e.NewEditIndex]
                                                 .FindControl("lbllnknm")).Text;
}
```

**Update 2:**

As per your comment you are trying to access the LinkButton text on click of LinkButton itself which means the event is raised by LinkButton itself. You can simply use the `sender` object like this:-

```
protected void OnUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton LinkButton2 = sender as LinkButton;
    GridViewRow row = LinkButton2.NamingContainer as GridViewRow; //Get the gridview row
    Label lblid = row.FindControl("lblid") as Label;
    string qouteid = lblid.Text;
}
```

Comment: i want to get label value. in label there is anchor tag

Comment: @krishnamohan - Yeah my bad! Updating, give me a min.

Comment: @krishnamohan - Check now.